# Swift declare class in class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Let me explain my question with an Example.

```
class Mother: NSObject {
var momVar:Int =5
var subClass : child(mylevel:5)   //  <-- ********    Error  //
init(){
    momVar=1000
    level=1
}

func print(){
    NSLog("%d",momVar);
}

func subMethod(){
    subClass =child(myVar: 5)  //  <== Doesnt Work either
    yazdir()
}
}
```

below child class:

```
class child:Mother{
    var someVar:Int=1
    init(myVar:Int) {
        super.init()
        someVar = myVar
    }

}
```

I want to use "child" class in "Mother" class. But i got " not initialized at super.init call" error. Other view controller calls "Mother" class with "print" method such as:

```
@IBAction func buttonTest(sender : AnyObject) {
   var mom=Mother()
   mom.yazdir()
```

}

The question is How i can use "child" class in "Mother" class? 
Thank you

Comment: what is `techTree`? I'm not seeing you've defined it... and that line `var subClass : techTree(mylevel:5)` should be syntactically like `var subClass = techTree(mylevel:5)` instead. what kind of error did you get anyway at the marked lines of code?

Comment: In addition to the `techTree` what is `yazdir()`? This doesn't compile for me at all as is.

Comment: techtree=child. I forget to change that:/ now i fix that. Sory for that

Comment: @holex. Thank you, You are my hero... IF you add your answer i will select you. Thanks again

Comment: @Antiokhos, I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line of code is not correct syntactically as is:

```
var subClass : child(mylevel:5)
```

you need to define the type after the `:` (before the `=` if there is any) or you can use it without explicit type, like:

```
var subClass = child(mylevel:5)
```